# Flutter Geocoding iOS locationFromAddress always return empty list

Tags: flutter, geocoding, reverse-geocoding, clgeocoder

I'm using the function locationFromAddress from plugin https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding. sending the same info (address, city) in both Android and iOS, android return the right coordinates(lat, long) but iOS(real device) always returns Null, although the placemarkFromCoordinates function does works fine in both(Android-iOS), What could be happening?

Comment: i just detect that the way in which the address is written(only in iOS, Android always work well) can cause no response to be returned, for example: when searching for an address like this: "carrera 9#73-12, Bogota" the response is null, but if you use an abbreviation and search for: "cra 9# 73-12, Bogota" then it returns the gps location, the problem that I find now is that those gps locations are sometimes not correct

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be coming from the geocodeAddressString function in the [iOS CLGeocoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clgeocoder), which is what pub.dev/packages/geocoding [uses to geocode addresses in iOS](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geocoding/blob/master/geocoding/ios/Classes/GeocodingHandler.m). This would use an entirely different service than the [Android Geocoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder), thus yielding sometimes very different results.

I suggest you take your questions and concerns about the iOS Geocoder to the [Apple Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/search/?q=geocodeAddressString) where other developers may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I just reported this issue:

this address:
"LHR - Heathrow Terminal 4, Sheffield Road, Longford, Hounslow, UK"
works on Android
iOs returns "Could not find any result for the supplied address or coordinates."

but this address
"Birmingham Airport (BHX), Trident Road, Birmingham, UK"
works on both
hope that helps